# MySQL service not starting due to new SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, mysql, windows-services

Yesterday I changed out my old SSD (with OS) to a new one, and I want to use the old SSD for a MySQL database. I have successfully cloned the disk, and my OS is working. I cleared the old data from the SSD and placed a MySQL database data folder on the old SSD.

Once I changed the MySQL data directory and tried to restart the server it gave me an error. After a while I noticed it was only a problem because of the drive itself. I changed the security of the SSD to 'everyone', but still it won't startup. Could my drive still be blocking a service? What am I overlooking?

Comment: What is *After a while I noticed it was only a problem because of the drive itself*. What specifically gave you that idea (error messages etc)?

Comment: I changed the datadir from the MySQL my.ini file to the default folder and it started working again through the services.msc

Comment: Make that an answer please

Comment: It's not the solution, because it's the default. I still want the MySQL data from my SSD (which is still blocked).

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for this yet :( Anyone?

Also my files on the drive are still at read-only, which I can't seem to change. Even after diskpart executing:
"attributes disk clear readonly"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this matter by firmware updating the SSD. I had to try several programs for this as it seemed kind of corrupted. A full format didn't even fix this issue, the manufacture had software that could update it. The old version of the program fixed it so the newer version software could detect it and update the software.